# Fetch posts by types in Objection.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js, objection.js

So I have a posts table and a types table. Each post can have many types. I have created a HasManyRelation relation in the post model. No, I wish to get all posts which have a type_id of maybe 1 or 2 whatever. This is what I have tried,

```
const posts = await UserPost.query()
            .select("id", "description", "price", "created_at")
            .eager("[user, category, images, types]")
             .modifyEager("types", builder => {
                 builder.where("user_post_type.type_id", 1)
             })
            .limit(limit)
            .orderBy("created_at", "desc");
```

This doesn't work. This just filters the types themselves. But doesn't actually return posts with that type. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eager makes before a query to get the Post and after a query for each eager you write in the arguments of `.eager()`.
If you want filter the Post by type you must join the tables, and add a condition with `.where()`. This is the first example that comes to mind:

```
const posts = await UserPost.query()
            .select("id", "description", "price", "created_at")
            .leftJoin('types')
            .eager("[user, category, images]")
            .where('types.type_id', 1) // Condition
            .limit(limit)
            .orderBy("created_at", "desc");
```

If you want see other example this is the [link for documentation](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/join-methods.html#joinrelated)